# What does "34 mill by 34 mill timbers" refer to in the video i have linked to

Tags: materials

In this [YouTube tutorial about sound proofing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPzbuEunSLk&feature=youtu.be&t=142) the host Refers to  34 mill by 34 mill timbers.

> you'll see this framework
>   that runs all the way around up, that's just
>   a soft wood frame attached on to the
>   inside wall.
>   it's 34 mill by 34 mill Timbers which is
>   a fairly standard size, and that just
>   goes all the way round.

Is he talking about a 34 mill by 34 mill timbers?

I searched that on [google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=PCY2XtC2JNPgrQHouo74CA&q=34%20mil%20by%2034%20mil%20size%20Timber&oq=34%20mil%20by%2034%20mil%20size%20Timber&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5732.13258..13810...0.2..0.330.1125.2-2j2......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i160j33i21.jNmJSXNx7k0&ved=0ahUKEwjQxMiH3LHnAhVTcCsKHWidA48Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) and [amazon](https://www.amazon.sg/s?k=34%20mil%2034%20mil%20Timber&ref=nb_sb_noss), got nothing relevant.

Given he said that is a standard size, What does “34 mill by 34 mill timbers” refer to ?

Comment: I don't feel like you really made an effort to google it, you just gave up at your first failed search.  I had no trouble with "34 x 34 timber".  If a Google search doesn't work out, you have to try other stuff.  it's a common European size apparently.  Basically our 2x2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically he used the word timbers for dimensional lumber or trim boards.

The term Timbers usually refer to large dimension framing members. 6x6  or larger.

34 millimeters is 1.34 inches which is not "pretty standard" in my world.

But i suspect it is the equivalent to a 2x2.

Comment: The video person is British.  Your world must be the EU, since it does not contain Britain.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - *That is why he was talking funny* ;)-. Its a happy little world i live in , I do not define it by geopolitical boundaries, it is the sum of my experiences and what i choose to put in it. To quote Bob Ross **"Maybe you want a happy little tree in your world"**.